# Can Open Sourced web frameworks be dangerous?

Tags: php, security, web, frameworks

I know open sourced web frameworks make a developers life easier and have security features built in. Some contain thousands of files and contributions from many developers which one could not hope to do on their own. But what I want to know is if using them can be dangerous.

For example could a framework contain viruses or record information about a web application and send that information to the framework's creator or some third party?

Comment: Technically yes, but it's incredibly unlikely for the big frameworks. Each contribution goes through an approval process

Answer (score 0):

> For example could a framework contain viruses or record information about a web application and send that information to the framework's creator or some third party?

A bigger concern here is "could they contain unknown vulnerabilities?" rather than "could they contain malware?" Open source is difficult to hide malware in, [but not impossible](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/01/on-design-and-implementation-stealth-backdoor-for-web-applications).